# debian package bittorrent usage - general way to find out usage of a debian package

Tags: debian

I installed the [debian package bittorrent](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/bittorrent).

The package description states that it "contains the tools which are used for console-only downloading. "

I expected that an executable named "bittorrent" will be made available somewhere, where my PATH environment variable is pointing to, such that I can use the executable from a shell.

doing so, i get

```
$ bittorrent
getbash: bittorrent: command not found
```

Trying the man pages for the package that I installed

```
$ man bittorrent
No manual entry for bittorrent
```

I honestly don't know what I can do now with this package.

To solve my problem at hand, I'm using rtorrent now.
However: How would I go about, in general and for this very example, if I want to find out how I use a debian package when there is no executable with the same name as the package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the linked page, you can see a [list of the files](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/all/bittorrent/filelist) the package installs

And of this list, a number are installed into /usr/bin which normally holds executables:

```
/usr/bin/btcompletedir.bittorrent
/usr/bin/btdownloadcurses.bittorrent
/usr/bin/btdownloadheadless.bittorrent
/usr/bin/btlaunchmany.bittorrent
/usr/bin/btlaunchmanycurses.bittorrent
/usr/bin/btmakemetafile.bittorrent
/usr/bin/btreannounce.bittorrent
/usr/bin/btrename.bittorrent
/usr/bin/btshowmetainfo.bittorrent
/usr/bin/bttrack.bittorrent
```

As Bit-torrent is a protocol, not a product there isn't really an ideal executable to 'run' as such - you **can** run the above executables, and they may all have man pages as well. Also, you can try running them and passing switches to them such as `-h` or `--help` which most executables support. However normally these are used by various bit torrent clients, to implement the functionality these clients provide.

It's similar to how you may install fonts on a system, but you're never going to 'run' the fonts, you make use of them.

**Edit**:

Another way to query the files in a package is via `dpkg-query`

```
dpkg-query -L bittorrent
```

will give you a list of the files the package would install.

Comment: the [list of files] on the webpage, that was what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: There's likely a way to list it directly from the package manager too, but as I don't use Debian generally I'm unsure what it is.

Comment: good thought. I just had a look: This can be done with `dpkg-query -L PACKAGE_NAME`